# How add modal window in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in Angular and I try to add a modal window:

my effort :

http://plnkr.co/edit/j9R70y6jEnQMeAklLEHU?p=preview

Have other methods how to add modal window and then close it by press in X, for example through directive ? Big thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I might do if I were you is look into existing solutions. Depending on how much you're going to want to study angular, this might be a better faster solution if all you want is a modal now:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

There's also angularstrap:

http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/modal

Comment: ok, angular ui is deprecated coz use bootstrap 2, and I want to the LOGIC  of using modal on plain angular through directives. If you saw your second link - please explain me why they are use so many js files for simple modal - http://plnkr.co/edit/xKP5PW3Dco1CczmCuuVN?p=preview. thanks